# Java GUI Best way to create a table of JTables?

Tags: java, layout, jframe, jtable, tablemodel

[UPDATE!!!!]
This is the finish product:

: )

[image][image]
So I am working on a program that helps me organize and print seatings for dinner. I have a student class with instance variables of their FirstName, LastName, etc. I also have a DinnerTable Class that has List of Student and String teacherName. I have created a GUI that so that it is easier to assign different seats. I already have one tab on JTabbedPane that organizes student information(if they are available or not) and randomizes the tables they sit. Now, to better visualize the tables and to make it easier to assign each student to a specific seat, I need to make something like this:
[image] 
I want to use the actual DinnerTable objects in the TableModel so that whenever I edit something on this Frame, the changes are translated to the objects. However, I am not really sure about what to do. Should I:

1.Create tables(one JTable for each DinnerTable) nested in the cells of a bigger JTable? But how can I perform actions such as swiping students between DinnerTable? Or
2.Align JTables in GridLayout or GridBagLayout? But again, how can I swap students?

Thank you!
      package DinnerList;

```
  public class Student 
  {
  private String lastName;
  private String firstName;
  private int grade;
  private int table;
  private boolean gender;//Male=true, female=false;
  private boolean available; //true=available;

public Student()
{
    lastName="";
    firstName="";
    grade=0;
    table=0;
    gender=true;
    available=true;
}
public Student(String l, String f, int i, boolean g, boolean a)
{

    lastName=l;
    firstName=f;
    grade=i;
    gender=g;
    available=a;
    //table is not written back to the txt.
    table=0;
}
//Getters

  public String getLastName()
   {
    return lastName;
  }
  public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}
public int getGrade()
{
    return grade;
}       
public int getTable()
{
    return table;
}
  public boolean getGender()
{
    return gender;
}
public boolean getAvailable()
{
    return available;
}

//Setters
public void setLastName(String s)
{
    this.lastName=s;
}
public void setFirstName(String s)
{
    firstName=s;
}
public void setGrade(int i)

{
    grade=i;
}
public void setTable(int hiahia)
{
    table=hiahia;
}
public void setGender(boolean b)
{
    gender=b;
}
public void setAvailable(boolean b)
{
    available=b;
}

//Miscellaneous
  public String toString()
  {
    String a="";

     a=lastName+","+firstName+","+Integer.toString(grade)+","+Boolean.toString(gender)+","+Boolean.toString(available);
    return a;
    }
 }
```

///////////////////////////////////

```
 package DinnerList;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

  public class DinnerTable 
{
    private List<Student> members= new ArrayList<Student>();
    private int tableNumber=0;
    private int capacity=0;
    private String teacherName="";
    private boolean available=true;

public DinnerTable(int a, int b, String c, boolean d)
{
    tableNumber=a;
    capacity=b;
    teacherName=c;
    available=d;
}

public void setTableNumber(int a) {tableNumber=a;}
public void setCapacity(int a) {capacity=a;}
public void setTeacherName(String a) {teacherName=a;}
public void setAvailable(boolean b) {available=b;}
public void add(Student s)
{
    if(available&&(members.size()<capacity))
    { this.members.add(s); }
    else if(!available)
    { System.out.println("Adding Student failed, table "+tableNumber+" not available");}
    else
    { System.out.println("Adding Student failed, table "+tableNumber+" is full");}
}

public int getTableNumber() 
{return tableNumber;}
public int getCapacity() {return this.capacity;}
public String getTeacherName() {return teacherName;}
public boolean getAvailable() {return available;}
public List<Student> getMembers(){return members;}
public void remove(Student s) 
{
    if(members.contains(s))
    {
        members.remove(s);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Failed to remove student from table because it wasn't there");
    }
  }
}
```

/////////////////////

```
package DinnerList;

import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class DinnerTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
          boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
{
    Object huahua =table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
    String ppp="";
    if(huahua!=null)
    {
        if(huahua instanceof Student)
        {
            ppp=((Student) huahua).getLastName()+", "+((Student)huahua).getFirstName();
        }
        else if(huahua instanceof String)
        {
            ppp=(String)huahua;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error: DinnerTableCellRenderer intakes unknown data type");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ppp="";
    }
    JLabel label = (JLabel)super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, ppp,isSelected, hasFocus,row, column);
    return label;
    }

}
```

//////////

```
package DinnerList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class DinnerTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModel
 {
    private final String[] columnNames={"","","",""};
    private List<DinnerTable> tableCollection= new ArrayList<DinnerTable>();


public DinnerTableModel(List<DinnerTable> huhu)
{
    tableCollection.addAll(huhu);
}
public int getColumnCount() 
{
    return columnNames.length;
}

public int getRowCount() 
{
        if(tableCollection.size()%4==0)
        {
            return tableCollection.size()/4;
        }
        else
        {
            return (int)(tableCollection.size()/4)+1;
        }
}

public String getColumnName(int col) 
{
    return columnNames[col];
}

public DinnerTable getTableAt(int row, int column)
{
        if(tableCollection.size()>=(Integer)((row)/8)+column+1)
        {
            return tableCollection.get((Integer)((row)/8)+column);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

}
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int colIndex) 
{
    DinnerTable dd= this.getTableAt(rowIndex, colIndex);
    String ss= "";
    if(dd==null)
    {
            return "";
    }
    else if(rowIndex%8==0)
    {
            return (dd.getTableNumber()+". "+dd.getTeacherName());
    }
    else if(dd.getMembers().size()>=rowIndex%8)
    {
            return dd.getMembers().get(rowIndex%8);
    }
    else
    {
            return "";
    }
}


public Class getColumnClass(int c) 
{
    return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
}
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) 
{
        if(this.getValueAt(row, col) instanceof Student)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {

  if(aValue instanceof Student)
  {
        if(rowIndex%8!=0)
        {
            if(null!=this.getTableAt(rowIndex,columnIndex))
            {
                this.getTableAt(rowIndex,columnIndex).getMembers().set(rowIndex%8-1, (Student)aValue);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("error: Attempting to put student in nonexistent table in table list gui");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("error: Attempting to put student in a string in table list gui");
        }
  }
  else if(aValue instanceof String)
  {
        System.out.println("error: Attempting to change teacher name in tablelist gui");
  }
  else
  {
        System.out.println("error: Attempting to set unknown object type in tablelist gui");
  }
}

}
```

////****************////

```
JTable tableTable= new JTable(new DinnerTableModel(tables));
for(int hihihi=0;hihihi<tableTable.getColumnCount();hihihi++)
{
  tableTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(hihihi).setCellRenderer(new   DinnerTableCellRenderer());
}
JScrollPane scrollpaneB1= new JScrollPane();
scrollpaneB1.add(tableTable);
panelB.add(scrollpaneB1);
```

Comment: From a layout perspetive, you could use either a `GridLayout` or a `GridBagLayout`, both will work, `GridBagLayout` is more complex, but will provide you with more options. From a data point of view, start by extending from a `AbstractTableModel`, for each of your objects, a corresponding table model should be created, which is used to manage them

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for replying(again)! I have built a TableModel already, but I feel that the "getValueAt" method can be really really buggy... Since the method is called by default to display the contents in each cell, it is supposed to return a String value. However, in order to swap Students between DinnerTables, I need a method that gets the actual Student at each cell whenever I click the cell. What do you think I should do?

Comment: *"Since the method is called by default to display the contents in each cell, it is supposed to return a String value"* - Actually, it can return any type of `Object`, you can then register a renderer (and editor) to deal with it

Comment: *"However, in order to swap Students between DinnerTables, I need a method that gets the actual Student at each cell whenever I click the cell"* - Then create a method in you custom `TableModel` to do it - or, as I said previously, return the actual `Student` object from `getVaueAt` and rely on a custom renderer to renderer it - no offence, but this `JTable` 101

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [Using Custom Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I will try the methods you mentioned. And I just started using swing a few days ago, so it is really JTable 101 for me : )

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just made a tableCellrenderer and a TableModel and I added them into my post. However, the program throws illegal argument exception. Could you help me see what's wrong?

Comment: You don't need `Object huahua =table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);`, just use the `value` passed to you by the caller, you also don't need `JLabel label = (JLabel)super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, ppp,isSelected, hasFocus,row, column);`, just set the text of the component, `DefaultTableCellRenderer` extends from `JLabel`, so you have all the functionality available from within the class itself

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry for so many questions... I ran the program and the jscrollpane appeared to completely blank... What do you think caused this? I added a portion of the code to the post. Thank you! : )

Comment: Since I don't have a fully runnable example which demonstrates your issue (I've been able to hack one together, but I get an index out of bounds issue), it's hard to say. I might suggest a slight change in design, where each `DinnerTable` is model separately in their own `TableModel` and `JTable`, this would greatly simplify things

Comment: @MadProgrammer I ran several tests on my program and found out that objects in my TableModel wasn't updated when the objects are modified... The solution I got from google was to add a TableModelListener. However, I have another Table that works pretty well, but I never added a TableModelListener to it. Do you know what I should do?

Comment: The model needs to be informed when a object changes, so it can trigger appropriate events to notify the table

Comment: @MadProgrammer I found your old answer on this topic and it works! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375129/java-tablemodel-not-updating But is there a more efficient way of doing this? It's not about the model telling the Table to update. The issue is that the object in model itself doesn't change.

Comment: The basic idea is, when the object changes, you need to tell the model. You could set up an observer pattern between the table model and object, so when the object is changed, it notifies the model which notifies the table

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's a little weird... So when a TableModel object is created, it takes the value of the parameter instead of the reference? What bothers me is that my other instance from the subclass of AbstractTableModel does change as the original object changes.(But it takes a list of the objects, unlike this one's taking just one object)

Comment: If the object is changed outside of the `TableModel`, then you MUST tell the `TableModel` that the object has changed, you can do this directly (as you've seen in one of my other posts) OR you could establish a observer pattern between the object and the `TableModel` (`PropertyChangeListener` would be an example), so when the object is changed, it generates a change event and all registered listeners get notified. This adds some more maintenance to the `TableModel`, as you need to register and deregister the listeners, but it decouples the object from the `TableModel`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am new to programming and have a lot of questions. It is very nice of you to be so patient! :  ) However, I have another JTable that intakes another TableModel class. I ran tests and it seems that the model does change whenever the original objects change, even though I didn't use any propertychangelisteners. This is very confusing to me...

Comment: I've added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am new to programming and have a lot of questions. It is very nice of you to be so patient! : ) However, I have another JTable that intakes another TableModel class. I ran tests and it seems that the model does change whenever the original objects change, even though I didn't use any propertychangelisteners. This is very confusing to me...

`JTable` is among one of the more complex components in the API (`JTree` and text components been the next), if you can become comfortable with it, you will be a long way to becoming comfortable with the overall API.

There are any number of ways you could notify the `TableModel` that an object has changed, but one of the best ways is to do it in a decoupled way, so you don't have to maintain a reference to the `TableModel` every where the `Student` object might change.

This suggests that the `Student` object itself should generate some kind of change event, which interested parties (like the `TabelModel`) can listen for and take action when they occur.

In this way, you can change the `Student` object anywhere in your code without caring about who might need to know that the object has changed.

Now, this basically boils down to an observer pattern, Swing implements this kind of functionality in it's listeners, `ChangeListener` springs to mind as a possible candidest, but `PropertyChangeListener` is a more powerful option, as it generates events based on the property that has changed.

In some cases, you probably won't care what property has changed, but in the case of `TableModel`, it's very useful.

This is a simple demonstration of the concept, using two tables.  You can edit any value in either table and the opposing table will be updated when the value is committed. Now, you could also modify the instance of `Student` in your code and you'd get the same result, but this was a simple example to create.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Student student = new Student("Skywalker", "Luke", 0, true, true);
                StudentTabelModel leftModel = new StudentTabelModel(student);
                StudentTabelModel rightModel = new StudentTabelModel(student);

                JTable leftTable = new JTable(leftModel);
                leftTable.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
                JTable rightTable = new JTable(rightModel);
                rightTable.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(leftTable));
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(rightTable));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class StudentTabelModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>(25);
        private PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener;

        public StudentTabelModel(Student... students) {
            propertyChangeListener = new StudentPropertyChangeListener();
            add(students);
        }

        public void add(Student... students) {
            if (students != null && students.length > 0) {
                int startRow = this.students.size();
                for (Student student : students) {
                    student.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);
                    this.students.add(student);
                }
                fireTableRowsInserted(startRow, this.students.size() - 1);
            }
        }

        public void remove(Student ...students) {
            if (students != null && students.length > 0) {
                for (Student student : students) {
                    int index = this.students.indexOf(student);
                    if (index != -1) {
                        student.removePropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);
                        this.students.remove(student);
                        fireTableRowsDeleted(index, index);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return students.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 6;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                    return String.class;
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    return Integer.class;
                case 4:
                case 5:
                    return Boolean.class;
            }
            return Object.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Student student = students.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return student.getLastName();
                case 1:
                    return student.getFirstName();
                case 2:
                    return student.getGrade();
                case 3:
                    return student.getTable();
                case 4:
                    return student.getGender();
                case 5:
                    return student.getAvailable();
            }
            return "??";
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Student student = students.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    student.setLastName(aValue == null ? null : aValue.toString());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    student.setFirstName(aValue == null ? null : aValue.toString());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (aValue instanceof Integer) {
                        student.setGrade((Integer) aValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (aValue instanceof Integer) {
                        student.setTable((Integer) aValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (aValue instanceof Boolean) {
                        student.setGender((Boolean) aValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    if (aValue instanceof Boolean) {
                        student.setAvailable((Boolean) aValue);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected class StudentPropertyChangeListener implements PropertyChangeListener {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getSource() instanceof Student) {
                    Student student = (Student) evt.getSource();
                    int row = students.indexOf(student);
                    if (row != -1) {
                        switch (evt.getPropertyName()) {
                            case "lastName":
                                fireTableCellUpdated(row, 0);
                                break;
                            case "firstName":
                                fireTableCellUpdated(row, 1);
                                break;
                            case "grade":
                                fireTableCellUpdated(row, 2);
                                break;
                            case "table":
                                fireTableCellUpdated(row, 3);
                                break;
                            case "gender":
                                fireTableCellUpdated(row, 4);
                                break;
                            case "avaliable":
                                fireTableCellUpdated(row, 5);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

    public class Student {

        private String lastName;
        private String firstName;
        private int grade;
        private int table;
        private boolean gender;//Male=true, female=false;
        private boolean available; //true=available;

        private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;

        public Student() {
            this("", "", 0, false, true);
        }

        public Student(String l, String f, int i, boolean g, boolean a) {

            lastName = l;
            firstName = f;
            grade = i;
            gender = g;
            available = a;
            //table is not written back to the txt.
            table = 0;
            propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
        }

        public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }

        public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }
//Getters

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public int getGrade() {
            return grade;
        }

        public int getTable() {
            return table;
        }

        public boolean getGender() {
            return gender;
        }

        public boolean getAvailable() {
            return available;
        }

//Setters
        public void setLastName(String s) {
            String old = lastName;
            this.lastName = s;
            propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("lastName", old, lastName);
        }

        public void setFirstName(String s) {
            String old = firstName;
            firstName = s;
            propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("firstName", old, firstName);
        }

        public void setGrade(int i) {
            int old = grade;
            grade = i;
            propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("grade", old, grade);
        }

        public void setTable(int hiahia) {
            int old = table;
            table = hiahia;
            propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("table", old, table);
        }

        public void setGender(boolean b) {
            boolean old = gender;
            gender = b;
            propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("gender", old, gender);
        }

        public void setAvailable(boolean b) {
            boolean old = available;
            available = b;
            propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("available", old, available);
        }

//Miscellaneous
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String a = "";

            a = lastName + "," + firstName + "," + Integer.toString(grade) + "," + Boolean.toString(gender) + "," + Boolean.toString(available);
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

Remember, this relies on the INSTANCE of the `Student` been shared, if you create two different instances of the `Student` object and expect that changes in one instance will be reflected in the other, then you will be disappointed

Comment: This is very helpful!!! If I want to update changes in my DinnerTable Object, should I do the same?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve, you want to provide a decoupled and self managed approach, then, yes, I would recommend it

Comment: Haha my program finally works now!  Although I didn't end up using propertychangelistener, your "refresh" method still helped me a lot! Thank you so much!

Comment: I put the results on the question. Now the program looks pretty neat : )